# Display arrays without using a loop in Excel VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have a problem displaying the results of the following code:

```
For i = 1 To UBound(files) Step 1    
    Workbooks.Open files(i)
    With ActiveWorkbook
        Module2.testfunction
        thisWb.Sheets(1).Range("A1:C" & Ubound(testfunction)) = testfunction
        .Close False
    End With
Next i
```

In each iteration of the for loop, there is a new workbook to which I apply the "testfunction". This function returns an array and I need to write this array to the workbook where the macro is running ("thisWb"). With each iteration there is a new array and this new one has to be displayed in the next range of columns, so as not to overlap the one displayed before (with a spacing of one column).

As the code is now, there is an overlapping. I want to find a way to iterate the range (in the column part) without having to resort to a loop with Cells().

Is it possible?

Comment: Huh. `cells()` would be the logical choice but maybe `offset` perhaps?

Comment: @findwindow `cells()` was my first thought but it took forever to display a single array. That's why I wanted to use `range()`. As I'm quite new to VBA, I didn't know the `offset` function but perhaps it would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (untested)

```
Dim wb As Workbook, v As Variant, lCol As Long

For i = 1 To UBound(Files)
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Files(i))
    With thisWb.Sheets(1)
        lCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 2
        v = testfunction
        .Range(.Cells(1, lCol), .Cells(UBound(v, 1), UBound(v, 2) + lCol)) = v
        wb.Close False
    End With
Next
```